# How can I throw my own custom message in @NonNull exception using lombok?

Tags: java, annotations, lombok

I started using lombok project, and I had a doubt. Let's supose I have a method with one argument `method(@NonNull arg)`. If I call that method with null argument `method(null)`, I will get the following exception: `java.lang.NullPointerException: arg`.

But let's supose I want that exception message says something like `arg cannot be null` instead of the other one (regardless of the sense of that message, I only want to know how to cusomize the exception message using @NonNull annotation).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Lombok's documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/NonNull), the `@NonNull` annotation just adds an if statement at the top of your function to check if its null. So *if you don't want to use any other library*, you could just do it yourself :

```
class NullArgumentException extends IllegalArgumentException {

    public NullArgumentException() {
        super("arg cannot be null");
    }
}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            foo(null);
        } catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // or System.out.println(e.getMessage())
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void foo(Integer i) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if(i == null) throw new NullArgumentException();
    }
}
```

Comment: In the meantime you can define a lombok.config to define @NonNull's behaviour, for instance the JDK default/standard nullcheck method, but it is not possible to define a custom message. See: https://projectlombok.org/features/NonNullhttps://projectlombok.org/features/NonNull

Answer (score 11):

You can't.

However, you can configure lombok to throw an IllegalArgumentException instead. That will have the message `arg is null`.

To configure this, add `lombok.nonNull.exceptionType = IllegalArgumentException` to your `lombok.config` file.

Disclosure: I am a lombok developer.

Comment: And you don't think it would be a nice feature to add? I mean imagine the method has two arguments method(arg1, arg2), and I want to throw an exception saying something like "arg1 and arg2 are mandatory".

Comment: What if I want to thrown a user defined exception ? Can it be done and How ?

Answer (score 1):

Lombok `@NonNull` do not allow this.
Try using `@NotNull(message = "arg cannot be null")` from `javax.validation.constraints` package.

Comment: But then you have to manually validate your objects whereas Nonull from Lombok does an automatic validation check on method calls.